# Printing Arabic to network printer (PHP)

Tags: php, printing, utf-8, arabic

I need to print Arabic text to a network printer using PHP.

**Code**

```
$ar = "عربي";

try {
    $fp = fsockopen("10.1.10.21", 9100);
    fputs($fp, $ar);
    close($fp);
    echo 'Successfully Printed';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

However, the result is garbage, so please, I need help.

Comment: Does your printer support the Windows-1256 encoding for Arabic text?

Comment: its canon runner 2206

Comment: Is it the windows operating system?

Comment: I've never used RAW print protocol but I assume it expects **commands**, not text (let alone UTF-8, which is a "relatively" new encoding). And you also need to figure out what exact raw printing language your printer speaks. Are you trying this because it works for English text, or it's just a wild guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it, I put my Arabic text in the div and then I print the div with JS by using `window.print()` method